# How can i get a log system similar with appengine(GAE) in django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, logging, web

To be more specific:

1. easy function call. like `logging.info(msg)`.
2. classified by request.
3. view from a admin console.

django is not required. any framework would be ok, or even a single python library.

Comment: This sounds redundant.  I don't get why you don't just use logging.info()

Comment: @dragonx but how can i check it in a webview?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logging` module is a Python built-in, not for Google App Engine only.

Take this: [Logging Module Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

for what you want it is simple to just use `logging.basicConfig()`

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

and the output will be like this:

```
DEBUG:root:This message should go to the log file
INFO:root:So should this
WARNING:root:And this, too
```

for integration to admin panel it's vary and depends the framework you're using, you could add a argument `file` to `basicConfig` ask logging module to save log in a file, then you could read it and parse it in Django

for instance it is:

```
logging.basicConfig(file="admin.log",level=logging.DEBUG)
```

is it what you want?